# JupyterLab does not execute code

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have a installation of Anaconda-Navigator which used to work on my Macbook, currently JupyterLab does not execute code when I try to run it.

1. I have uninstalled and reinstalled
2. I shift + enter to run a code block "print("a")" but nothing happens, it just shows [*] -- which I think it means it is processing, nothing actually prints out.
3. I have tried to restart the kernal

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4LUP.png)

Would appreciate your input.

Answer (score -1):

Check if your kernel is running. You can do this by checking your terminal.

Answer (score -2):

I encounter the same problem! I just refresh it and try again, then it works.